# How to select a particular list item if there is a duplicate also present

Tags: c#, html, coded-ui-tests

I have a HtmlList with items as 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4
I wish to select 3 which is the last but one element.

I am unable to select the particular list item.

I tried the following code block

```
HtmlListItem listitem = new HtmlListItem(this.UIMap.Rightlist);
listitem.FilterProperties[HtmlListItem.PropertyNames.TagInstance]= "19";
listitem.FilterProperties[HtmlListItem.PropertyNames.InnerText] = "3";
```

where RightList is a HtmlList and the taginstance of the item is 19. It is not able to identify the item and is selecting HtmlListItem at random. Can somebody suggest an alternate way to achieve this.

Appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the:

```
FindMatchingControls()
```

something like this:

```
var controls = listitem.FindMatchingControls()
```

and than figure out the index of the desired list item and select it

```
Mouse.Click(controls[index])
```